# Angular JS Services and Controllers in Different Files Causes Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angularjs project, I have the following files:

/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title></title>

  <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
  <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
  -->

  <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom Libraries -->
  <script src="lib/Shake.js"></script>

  <!-- your app's js -->

  <script src="js/services/CloudDatabases.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="starter">
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
</html>
```

/js/apps.js

```
// Ionic Starter App
// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    // Register stopping and starting analytics on app open and close
    document.addEventListener("pause", window.analytics.Stop(), false);
    document.addEventListener("resume", window.analytics.Start(), false);

    // Exit the application if you go offline
    document.addEventListener("offline", function(){}, false);
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

    ....
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

/js/services/CloudDatabases.js

```
angular.module('starter.services')
.service('CloudDatabases', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var urlBase = '/api/customers';

    this.getDatabases = function () {
        console.log('CloudDatabases.getDatabases();');
        return 'test getDatabasesResponse';
    };
}])
```

/js/controllers.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['CloudDatabases'])

// Login controller
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $http, $ionicPopup, $rootScope,     $state, $ionicViewService, CloudDatabases) {
  CloudDatabases.getDatabases();

  // Form data for the login modal
  $scope.loginData = {};

  // Try loading the loing data from storage if the user has already logged in
  $scope.loginData.username = window.localStorage['username'] || '';
  $scope.loginData.password = window.localStorage['password'] || '';
  $scope.loginData.uk = window.localStorage['uk'] || false;

  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.doLogin = function() {
    // Show the loading overlay so the user knows we are busy
    $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Loading...'});     

    // Save the login data to local storage so if the user closes the app they
    // don't have to re-enter it
    window.localStorage['username'] = $scope.loginData.username;
    window.localStorage['password'] = $scope.loginData.password;
    window.localStorage['uk'] = $scope.loginData.uk;

    // Build login JSON from form
    var login_json = JSON.stringify({auth: {passwordCredentials: {username:     $scope.loginData.username, password: $scope.loginData.password}}});

    // POST the actual authentication request
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens',
        data: login_json,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then(function(response) {

      // Save the auth token and tenant id for later use
      $rootScope.userData = [];
      $rootScope.userData.Token = response.data.access.token.id;
      $rootScope.userData.Tenant = response.data.access.token.tenant.id;
      $rootScope.userData.RawServices = response.data.access.serviceCatalog;

      // Use viewservice to hide back button on next page and remove login from nav stack
      $ionicViewService.nextViewOptions({
        disableBack: true
      }); 

      // Track successful logins
      window.analytics.trackFeature("Login.Success");

      $ionicLoading.hide();

      // Navigate to Servers page
      $state.go('app.servers');
    }, 
    function(response) {
      // Track failed logins
      window.analytics.trackFeature("Login.Failure");

      $ionicLoading.hide();
    });
  };
})
....
```

But this throws an error saying that it can't be injected.

Can anyone help with why that might be? It says that starter.services isn't defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because of your service definition. You are using service definition without `dependency array []` as second parameter. This tells angular to treat it as getter method for module `starter.services` instead of defining the module. Use below code for `starter.services` to fix this.

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.service('CloudDatabases', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var urlBase = '/api/customers';

    this.getDatabases = function () {
        console.log('CloudDatabases.getDatabases();');
        return 'test getDatabasesResponse';
    };
}])
```